# How to split a string stored in list<*> , then insert to same list using linq style or lambda ?

Tags: c#, linq, split

I have Writen o code using linq

```
var result=from m in driver_list select(m.Email,m.LisancePlate)
```

My code Output is like this

sample1@company.com;sample2@company.com----34 KZ 7898   sample3@company.com;sample2@company.com---- 34 TZK  6785

I want to a new output using my result like this  sample1@company.com---34 KZ 7898  sample2@company.com---34 KZ 7898   sample3@company.com---34 TZK 6785   sample2@company.com---34 TZK 6785

Comment: The code you've written wouldn't even compile, so that's clearly not the code giving that output. Please write your *real* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given output i quess you have a List like:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>()
{
    "sample1@company.com;sample2@company.com----34 KZ 7898",
    "sample3@company.com;sample2@company.com---- 34 TZK 6785"
};
```

The following will produce the requested output:

```
var result = 
test
.Select 
(
    t =>new 
    {
        Emails =  t.Split(new string[] { "----" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0],
        LicensePlate = t.Split(new string[] { "----" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]
    }
)
.Select 
(  
    t => new
    {
        Email = t.Emails.Split(';'),
        t.LicensePlate}
    )
.SelectMany 
( 
    t => t.Email,
    (x,t)=>new {Email = t,CarPlaket = x.LicensePlate)
)
.ToList();

foreach(var email in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}---{1}",email.Email,email.CarPlaket;)
```

The above solution will not put the results in the same list, but it will create a new list.

Comment: I am very sorry  output what ı want to see is like this 

   sample1@company.com---34 KZ 7898  
   sample2@company.com---34 KZ 7898  
   sample3@company.com---34 TZK 6785  
   sample2@company.com---34 TZK 678  

'---' is not important  this is like this 
Console.Writeline("{0}---{1}", a.Email,a.CarPlaket)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use `Regex` because the you have multiple `spaces` in `34 KZ 7898`. I've tried this code and it works as you expect:

```
string input = "sample1@company.com;sample2@company.com----34 KZ 7898 sample3@company.com;sample2@company.com---- 34 TZK 6785";
var result = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(input, "\\s(?=\\S+@)")
                             .Select(x=>{
                                var s = x.Split(new string[] {"----"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                return string.Join(" ",s[0].Split(';').Select(e => e + "----" + s[s.Length - 1]).ToArray());
                             }).ToArray());//No need ToArray() since .NET 4.0
//Output
sample1@company.com---34 KZ 7898 sample2@company.com---34 KZ 7898 sample3@company.com---34 TZK 6785 sample2@company.com---34 TZK 6785
```

Comment: @Anirudh of course, I think that's the **fixed** format. The OP was not very clear on this. I didn't even think there were more 2 emails.

Answer (score 0):

.Net's regex engine supports group captures in lookaround..So it becomes simple!

```
string input="sample1@company.com;sample2@company.com----34 KZ 7898 sample3@company.com;sample2@company.com---- 34 TZK 6785";
String[] emailValues=Regex.Matches(input,@"(\w+@\w+[.]\w+)(?=.*?(-+.*?)(?=\s*\w+@|$))")
                          .Cast<Match>()
                          .Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value+x.Groups[2].Value)
                          .ToArray();
```

This would work with arbitrary number of emailid's

Answer (score 0):

```
var src_in_arac = from log in Src_Log_List.ToList()
                              join ml in mail_arac_sorgu on log.Node equals ml.TasitTanımaNo
                              join sr in surucu_list.Select(ss =>
                              {
                                  string SCKartNo = "";
                                  string AdSoyad = ss.AdSoyad;

                                  if (ss.SrcKardId != "")
                                      SCKartNo = "000" + (Convert.ToInt64(ss.SrcKardId).ToString("X"));
                                  return new { AdSoyad, SCKartNo };

                              })
                              on log.SCID equals sr.SCKartNo
                              into data
                              from ss in data.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where log.Task == "GPSEvents"


                              select new { log.Speed, AdSoyad = (ss == null ? "İZİNSİZ KULLANIM" : ss.AdSoyad), ml.Plaka, log.OdoMeter, log.StandStill, log.Date, ml.Grup, ml.Email ,log.SC};
```

My Code is above. I am sorry my bad english. Mail Fields is ml.Email , I want to split mails joined with ';' chacter. Then into the sama string.